# How to make watch-depth in ngReact work

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

Currently, I try to integrate an `AngularJS` app with `React`.

I use the following library https://github.com/davidchang/ngReact

By using `watch-depth`, I expect React component will re-render itself, when AngularJS's scope data is changing.

My code looks like this

### index.html

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello React</title>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/react/react.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ngReact/ngReact.min.js"></script>
    <script src="build/commentbox.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['react']);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.firstName= "John";
        $scope.lastName= "Doe";

        setTimeout(function() { 
            alert('assign data! how to trigger react component?');
            $scope.data = {data : [
                {author: "Pete Hunt", text: "This is one comment"},
                {author: "Jordan Walke", text: "This is *another* comment"}
            ]};       
        }, 5000);
    });
    app.value('CommentBox', CommentBox);
</script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
    <br>
    Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
    <react-component name="CommentBox" props="data" watch-depth="reference"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

### commentbox.js

```
// tutorial4.js
var Comment = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="comment">
        <h2 className="commentAuthor">
          {this.props.author}
        </h2>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

// tutorial10.js
var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    console.log("DEBUG");
    console.log(this.props);
    var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function (comment) {
      return (
        <Comment author={comment.author}>
          {comment.text}
        </Comment>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        {commentNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

// tutorial1.js
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {


    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <CommentList data={this.props.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

There's no difference, whether I'm using `watch-depth="reference"` or `watch-depth="value"`. `React` component won't render itself, when value is assigned to `$scope.data`

Is there anything I had missed out?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$scope.data.push()` to add new data and  watch-depth="value"

It will re-render.